# How to track individual PC IP address in remote server when they connect to public WIFI?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to track the user System IP address which is like 192.168.0.1 along with remote server IP which is like 101.44.222.23. 
I used the below code but it is showing Remote server IP address (i.e, 101.44.222.23). My actual requirement is - when user visits my website I need to track thier::
**PC IP Address: 192.168.0.32** 
 **Server IP: 101.44.222.23**.
Please suggest me how to track it using PHP.

```
//It gives Server IP address

$localIp = gethostbyname(gethostname());

//It also gives same Server IP address
$ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
$ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
}

elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
}

else {
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

echo $ip;
```

Comment: Is there `ngInx` configured?

Comment: can you elaborate more on what your are trying to do ?

Comment: I edited the question clearly. Please help me out

Comment: The IP address of the user (the client) is in $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
The IP address of the website (the server) is in $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
This in the only information available, and probably the only information you need.

Comment: @RWC I placed these two lines ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; --- $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];) in my website code and when I check from my partner system who also connected to the same Network. But in my partner system also getting the same IP addresses. But my question I want to get 2 different IP addresses for 2 Systems/PC's. Hope you got my point..

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't...

Comment: Short and sweet.

Comment: Actually my friend is getting some spam messages in the application. In order to figure out that victim we are tracing system IP address with Host IP. In that case we can give warn to him.